# Will iOS app accepted on app store if 80% of UI is rendered on UIWebView and 20% being native OCR

Tags: ios, iphone, ocr, appstore-approval

I have a mobile website which at high level provides these functionalities:

1. Sign-in
2. Sign-up
3. Few forms where user can fill his additional details
4. Providing some capabilities to user based on information provided by
   him

Now I want to integrate OCR capabilities such as:

1. ID card scan
2. Debit card scan
3. Void check scan

So that some of the forms can be automatically filled by information extracted from these.

I am planning to make a native app in iOS consuming most of the forms, flow from my mobile website by rendering respective weburls on webview, and integrating vendor SDKs to provide OCR capabilities.

My question is -

> Will apple accept my iOS app in app store if I have 80% of flow, UI
>   rendered on UIWebView and remaining 20% being integration and use of
>   native vendor SDKs for OCR capabilities?

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Appstore approval process.

Comment: np, any ideas on where can I post this question? probably some other stack exchange site?

Comment: @Miraaj you could accept my answer anyway if it suits you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer :) I was able to find a suitable platform to post my query and I have got a helpful answer as well :) here is the link: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201079/6540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apple wouldn't accept such apps, apps made with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) wouldn't be on the app store. And for sure there are: http://phonegap.com/app/